# Moving from Macbook Pro Core 2 Duo 2.66 Ghz to 2.0 quod-core i7. Is it worh it?

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro

At the moment I have the `APPLE MacBook Pro MB985B/A 15.4" 320GB/4GB RAM/1.66Ghz` computer and I am thinking to buy `Apple MacBook Pro MC721LL/A 500GB 15.4" i7 MC721`. The price difference is only GBP 300. (I got a buyer for my old mac already)

Is it worth it? The main reason to upgrade the computer is general speed issues. (specifically, while browsing with FireFox, slow rendering time using Photoshop; from time to time I like to turn on some games)

Comment: I suggest you get an SSD instead.

Comment: What difference does it make?

Comment: They are [really fast](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4186/ocz-vertex-3-preview-the-first-client-focused-sf2200/5). Read up on them [here](http://blog.superuser.com/category/ssd/).

Comment: Getting an SSD will definitely speed up things a little bit. Chances are the "normal" HDD in the new one might become a bottleneck once again.

Comment: Also, please take a better look at the [FAQ]. You've already had a shopping recommendation question closed before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quad core processor will help if you run a lot of tasks which could be made
to run in parallel on the CPU (and if the CPU processing is a bottleneck).

Given the usage that you point out, you'd probably notice a far larger speed
improvement if you used a solid state drive. They're not cheap, but it'll be
night and day.

Comment: I can't seem to find any Macbook Pros with SSD. How would I search for them? Is there any special way they identify them in the model name?

Comment: If you aren't buying direct from Apple they will be hard to find, as they are optional extras that will only be in BTO (built-to-order) machines. And Apple SSDs are expensive with a capital E. Even more so than normal ones. The SSD comments are encouraging you to add an SSD to your current Mac.

Comment: Would it be possible to install SSD myself into macbook?

Comment: @Guy absolutely. There are some nice guides at [iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/) for almost every model.

Comment: Blah, beat me to it. :P

Comment: Great. That sounds like something I am going to do then. Going back to my initial question. Should I generally expect this computer to work generally then my old one? (both are named in the question), i.e. is 2.66 Ghz dual core better than 2.0 quad core?

Comment: The Sandy Bridge i7 will kick your old Core 2's ass, but your workload described above does not seem CPU-limited with the possible exception of Photoshop. If you want to spend the money, by all means, it's a great machine and it will serve you well, but for £300, you'll see a bigger improvement from the SSD.

Comment: I think I will buy this and then use eBay to buy SSD (do I need any specific SDD?) and as well upgrade RAM to 8GB (that is possible, right?).

Comment: Yes, Apple considers RAM to be user upgradable as well. However, I'm not sure buying SSDs off of eBay is necessarily all that wise. Right now there's a lot of press about SSDs having relatively short lifespans. They're still great, but buying a used one potentially limits the life of your machine. No, you don't need a specific SSD, but faster is better.

Comment: No, I didn't mean to buy a used SSD. Anyhow, would you recommend any online shop?

Comment: Haha, no, and shouldn't. We don't make shopping recommendations on SuperUser. There are lots of reputable online retailers though, I'm sure you can find one.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know it is against SuperUser TOS. Would you recommend any specific SSD? : )